# scroll to a certain point in the page automatically using css

Tags: html, css, scroll, vertical-scrolling

Is there a css parameter I can give to the body element that tells it to scroll to a certain point by default? For example, something like:

```
body {
    default-scroll-y: 200px;
}
```

If not, is there another way I can describe scrolling distances as heights in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in CSS.
You could trigger it with JavaScript/jQuery.
You could either use a plugin for that:

- http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Or implement it on your own, which would not be to hard I guess.

Comment: thanks! the link is a bit above my head, but now I know that CSS isn't enough to do everything.